# angular service call within success of previous service call

Tags: angularjs, service, nested

I have three angular service call in which service call 2 and 3 are should be made on the result of an value from the 1st service call. But my code is not hitting the second service call at all. Please find the code snippet below.

```
  datacontext.GetUnitRegistration(serialNumber, customerId).then(function (response) {     //1st service call   
            vm.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
            vm.UnitRegistration = response;
            vm.errorMsg = config.constantValues.NoRecordsFoundMsg;

                    document.getElementById('hdnHasClaims').value = vm.UnitRegistration.UnitWarranty.isEligWarr;

                    if (vm.UnitRegistration.UnitWarranty.isEligWarr == true) {
                        datacontext.GetUnitComfortPlanClaimList(serialNumber).then(function (result) {//2ndst service call   
                            if (result.Success == false) {
                                vm.exceptionMsg = vm.exceptionMsg + result.responseText;
                                vm.HasException = true;
                                vm.HasComfortPlanClaimsResults = false;

                            }
                            else {
                                if (result.length == 0) {
                                    vm.HasComfortPlanClaimsResults = false;
                                }
                                else {

                                    vm.HasComfortPlanClaimsResults = true;
                                }

                                $scope.ComfortPlanGrid.data = result;

                            }
                            spinner.spinnerHide();
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            spinner.spinnerHide();

                        });

                        datacontext.GetUnitStandardClaimList(serialNumber).then(function (result) { //3rd service call   
                            if (result.Success == false) {
                                vm.exceptionMsg = vm.exceptionMsg + result.responseText;
                                vm.HasException = true;
                                vm.HasUnitStandardClaimList = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                if (result.length == 0) {
                                    vm.HasUnitStandardClaimList = false;
                                }
```

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: did you verified browser console for response? are you getting any javascript error ? I would suggest put some console.log inside your method will give you more insight.

Comment: My guess is that the first `.then` success handler is throwing an error because `.fail` is undefined.  `.fail` should be `.catch`.